# What's wrong with RHEL 6.5 on POWER in a PowerKVM guest?

Tags: linux-kvm, rhel-6

I am seeing errors on two PowerKVM (Ver 2.1 SP1) systems on booting to the console of the form:

```
irq: irq 4110 on host null mapped to virtual irq 27 
BUG: Bad page state in process vballoon  pfn:03f6c 
page:c0000003ff4117a0 flags:0003f00000000824 count:0 mapcount:0  mapping:c0000003f837d970 index:58879 (Not tainted) 
Call Trace: 
[c0000003ee323b70] [c000000000012ee4] .show_stack+0x74/0x1c0 (unreliable) 
[c0000003ee323c20] [c000000000164178] .bad_page+0x168/0x1c0 
[c0000003ee323cb0] [d0000000036f068c] .release_pages_by_pfn+0x8c/0xd0 [virtio_balloon] 
[c0000003ee323d50] [d0000000036f0778] .leak_balloon+0xa8/0x100 [virtio_balloon] 
[c0000003ee323de0] [d0000000036f0dc0] .balloon+0x2e0/0x304 [virtio_balloon] 
[c0000003ee323ed0] [c0000000000bf04c] .kthread+0xbc/0xd0 
[c0000003ee323f90] [c000000000033a44] .kernel_thread+0x54/0x70 
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
```

On another system with same PowerKVM version, these messages do not appear. The behavior of the guest after these messages is unpredictable, sometimes continuing to boot, other times hanging with one or more CPU's spinning (reports of CPU soft-lockup have appeared on one guest but not reliably ). On all three PowerKVM hosts, I am seeing out to the `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/<domain>.log` a message like:

```
virtio-balloon: Buggy guest detected, disabling balloon
```

Answer (score 0):

From colleagues..

The balloon driver in RHEL 6.5 is broken.   Not sure if that's a generic statement or applicable only to POWER systems.

The "fix" is to disable it altogether `<memballoon model='none' />` in the domain file which causes the RHEL6.5 guests to be a lot happier.